# Fill Missing Values for a certain range with only Non-Missing Observation

Tags: excel, sas, formula

Hi I wonder how to put this in to SAS code:

My data looks like this:

```
Balance | Month | Outstanding
--------+-------+-------------- 
1000    | 0     |
200     | 1     |   
300     | 2     |
400     | 3     |
500     | 4     |
800     | 5     |
750     | 6     |
650     | 7     |
740     | 8     |
580     | 9     |
650     | 10    |
523     | 11    | 7093
654     | 12    |
458     | 0     |
789     | 1     |
852     | 2     |
236     | 3     |
1258    | 4     |
4528    | 5     |
78520   | 6     |
1258    | 7     |
4821    | 8     |
15870   | 9     |
1587    | 10    |
1599    | 11    | 111776
6520    | 12    |
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Balance | Month | Outstanding
--------+-------+------------
1000    | 0     | 7093
200     | 1     | 7093
300     | 2     | 7093
400     | 3     | 7093
500     | 4     | 7093
800     | 5     | 7093
750     | 6     | 7093
650     | 7     | 7093
740     | 8     | 7093
580     | 9     | 7093
650     | 10    | 7093
523     | 11    | 7093
654     | 12    | 7093
458     | 0     | 111776
789     | 1     | 111776
852     | 2     | 111776
236     | 3     | 111776
1258    | 4     | 111776
4528    | 5     | 111776
78520   | 6     | 111776
1258    | 7     | 111776
4821    | 8     | 111776
15870   | 9     | 111776
1587    | 10    | 111776
1599    | 11    | 111776
6520    | 12    | 111776
```

Basically I want to fill up the empty cells for the whole month 0-12 range with the sum of balance from month 0-11 and do to for the next set of month 0-12.

In Excel I can do this by using this formaula. Assume here that the column number for balance is A, Month is B, and outstanding is C:

```
=IF(B2=0,SUM(A2:A13),C1)
```

And then just drag the formula down for the moving sum

I am just not sure how to create the equivalent in SAS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up the input data as:

```
data have;
  input balance month outstanding;
  datalines;
1000     0      .
200      1      .   
300      2      .
400      3      .
500      4      .
800      5      .
750      6      .
650      7      .
740      8      .
580      9      .
650      10     .
523      11     7093
654      12     .
458      0      .
789      1      .
852      2      .
236      3      .
1258     4      .
4528     5      .
78520    6      .
1258     7      .
4821     8      .
15870    9      .
1587     10     .
1599     11     111776
6520     12     .  
;
```

You can combine the data with itself to get the desired result as follows:

```
data want;
  set have(where=(outstanding ne .));

  do until (month=12);
    set have(drop=outstanding);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A moving sum can be done with `PROC EXPAND`:

```
proc expand data=have
            out=want;
   by <by variables>;
   convert balance = outstanding / transform=(movsum 12);
run;
```

Your question is not entirely clear and needs to be reformatted, but `proc expand` is going to do what you want. You can read the syntax on the [SAS website](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#expand_toc.htm).

Comment: Hi, i tried using the proc expand, however, I wanted to have all the cells to have similar values and not a cumulative total.
DO you know how i should proceed with this? Thanks.